# Common preprocessor macros for all configurations of a target in XCode iPhone Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macros, target

I usually have four configurations per target (Debug, Release, Distribution, Ad Hoc) for my Apps.

Is there a way to add a common macro for all 4 of them, while not destroying the macros that I have set so far (you see "multiple values" in the editor).

Thanks in advance,
Obiwahn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the macro in the prefix header file (will be included in all source files).

Comment: Absolutely! The only macros defined per configuration should be those that vary per configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Another way do do this, which might work better for certain cases, is to use the $(inherited) macro to include the settings from the parent context. This works well with the way Xcode 4 lets you see the settings cascade.

Answer (score 0):

You could have all of your targets use the same .xcconfig file; see [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/xcodebuildsettings.html) under the heading "Build Configuration Files".  Note that even though the screenshots are out of date, the material seems to be accurate.