# Preprocessor Macro changes both targets

Tags: xcode

I have a project with two targets, a normal and a lite version. I want to distinguish between the two versions using an #ifdef LITE_VERSION. However, when I add this Macro to the preprocessor macros in the build settings, it is added to both targets.

How do I set a Preprocessor define that is specific to only the selected target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you adding it to the project's build settings or the target's build settings? It sounds like you're adding it to the project's build settings which will cause it to be used in all of the project's targets.

Comment: I was indeed changing the preprocessor macros at the wrong level (Project level) instead of Target Level (one column to the left) in XCode 4.

Went back to XCode 3.2.6 to see if it actually would work there and it did :-)

XCode 4 takes some getting used to...

Comment: A nice addition to Xcode 4 that I found helpful for build setting is to switch from the combined view to the levels view.  When you select the target you then get a resolved column which is the value that's going to be used for the build, a target column, a project column, and a column that shows the default value.  You can edit a value from both the target and project column.  I like it since I can tell from the one view where the final build value is being set and easily modify it a the level I want to have it set at.

Comment: Is there a way to set some preprocessor macros at the project level and add some target specific ones at the target level? Or is this a new topic?

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure.  The target settings usually override the project settings, but I'm not sure if there's a way to "pull" the project settings into the target's settings.

Comment: Found this on my of topic question which I shouldn't have posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787155/common-preprocessor-macros-for-all-configurations-of-a-target-in-xcode-iphone-pro